# How to select data and count from column with same id

Tags: mysql

[image: Problem image]

In my image, we can see the thread_id is repeated two times and the user_id is different.

How can I select count(thread_id)=2 data or count(thread_id)=1? You can see in the case of 'thread_id=3' there is only one entry. If it is in if conditional statement it would be better please help, I need a query

Comment: do you want any one of the userid??

Comment: Try posting the code/solutions you have tried yourself for solving the problem instead of direct posting your requirement and expect the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want something like this?

```
Select thread_id, COUNT(user_id) as users FROM TABLE GROUP BY thread_id
```

The results would look a little like this (based on the data I can see)

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║  thread_id ║ users ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1          ║  2    ║
║ 2          ║  2    ║
║ 3          ║  1    ║
║ 4          ║  2    ║
║ 5          ║  2    ║
║ 6          ║  1    ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Yes like this but i need a condition here i will get the result by Select COUNT(user_id) as users_count FROM TABLE GROUP BY thread_id having users_count=1 or i can change the users_count=2 i need a conditional query in here

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT  COUNT(user_id) as COUNT, thread_id 
FROM table
GROUP BY thread_id"
```